# maui MediaElement Position not updated when the video is paused

Tags: c#, maui, maui-community-toolkit

[image]

(The video has been paused and I am attempting to drag the progress bar to seek forward or backward, but unfortunately the Position property is not being updated)

I would like to obtain the video position when I click a button, regardless of whether the video is playing or not.

However, I have noticed that when the video is paused and I drag the progress bar, the video position is not updated accordingly.

The position is only updated when I click the play button.

My XAML code uses the basic MediaElement with default playback controls:

```xml
<toolkit:MediaElement x:Name="MediaElement" ShouldAutoPlay="False" ShouldShowPlaybackControls="True" HeightRequest="500" Source="local file"/>
```

And this is the code written to the console in the above figure

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MediaElement.PositionChanged += ((sender, args) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Position:{args.Position}");
        });
    }
```

To resolve this issue, I had to implement a workaround by calling Play and delaying the update for 500 milliseconds:

```
    private async void MarkStartButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MediaElement.Play();
        // call Play won't update Position immediately so give it a delay
        await Task.Delay(500); 
        _startPoint = MediaElement.Position - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
        UpdateTimePoint();
    }
```

Although this solution works, it is not ideal and I would like to find a better way.
One option is to create custom playback controls, but I would prefer to use the default controls if possible. Is there any way to obtain the updated video position when the video is paused?

Comment: I am afraid you cannot do this. As it is stated in [MediaElement Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/mediaelement#determine-mediaelement-status), MediaElement does not advance its Position property when  it is in Paused status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Paused indicates that the MediaElement does not advance its Position property. If the MediaElement was playing video, it continues to display the current frame.

As it is stated in the [Determine MediaElement status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/mediaelement#determine-mediaelement-status), MediaElement does not advance its Position property when it is in Paused status. So far you cannot do this. You could raise an issue on [Github](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues).